# Teradata SQL - how to get everything before hyphen?

Tags: sql, teradata

The question is how to get all data before hyphen using SQL in Teradata?

The pattern is like this : 123ABC-456. I need only 123ABC.

This regex expression:

```
SELECT RegExp_Replace('123ABC-456',  '\w[^-]*$')
```

returns "123ABC-" with hyphen for some reason

and this `"^[^-]*[^ -]"` - returns `"-456"` instead of `"123ABC"`

Please any help?

Comment: What if there's no hyphen? Do you want the whole string or an empty string?

Comment: I see you've accepted the answer below, but regexp_substr seems like overkill to me. `STRTOK(<column>,'-',1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('123ABC-456',  '^[^-]*[^ -]')
```

Comment: thank you, this worked. but what's the difference? regex expression anyway should give data before hyphen?

Comment: When I test it using RegExp_Replace() it didn't work, but REGEXP_SUBSTR() it gives the correct val, but the expression is same for both case